# Problem with Join in SQL with 2 databases

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am not so good at sql server. I am trying to do something like this

```
Select * from Page_Image_ID, PageID, DI_ImageID, caption, sort_order 
from Merchant_Subpages_images 
where PageID = 12345
```

This gets me right values. My problem here is that for every DI_ImageID, there is a row in a an other table from other database which i want along with the above result.

For each DI_ImageID, Select * from DI_Image from Images where DI_ImageID = @(all above IDs)

How is it possible, guys? Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can INNER JOIN on the common field;

```
Select 
   S.Page_Image_ID,
   S.PageID,
   S.DI_ImageID, 
   S.caption, 
   S.sort_order,
   I.*
from Merchant_Subpages_images S 
   inner join otherdbname.dbo.Images I ON S.DI_ImageID = I.DI_ImageID
where S.PageID = 12345
```

Comment: Alex is right, you will reference the table within the other database via DatabaseName.SchemaName.OtherTableName.